# How to enable Camera in ioS 7 device?

Tags: iphone

How to enable Camera in iOS 7 device (not in iOS8+) even after I click "don't allow" in camera access prompt?

Comment: If someone clicks "Don't allow" then I believe you are not going to be able to enable it, and doing that against the wishes of the user would be bad behavior.

Comment: After some research I found that in iOS7, all applications are granted with camera access. So there is no way that we can disable camera for specific application like in iOS8 and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default camera is enabled in iOS7. But in iOS8 the device prompts an alert message "App would like to access camera" with "Allow" and "Don't Allow" button.